# How to reload a package in Julia?

Tags: visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook, package, julia

I have installed `Metalhead.jl` package via `Pkg` and I am using that installation for development. Every time I make a change in the folder, I test behavior of the package in a Jupyter Notebook opened on VS Code. The problem is that, once  I have run the following line:

```
using Metalhead
```

Rerunning it does not load the Metalhead package again. I have to quit the Notebook, open it again and run that line to see a change in behavior. Is there a way to reload the package without quitting the Notebook?

Comment: I would suggest checking out the [Revise.jl package](https://github.com/timholy/Revise.jl) -- it is almost an essential part of developing codes in Julia IMO. I know it works in Jupyter notebooks, and in VS Code, but I am not sure how it integrates with VS Code notebooks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're working on a package locally, make sure to clone it via `Pkg` in dev mode:

```
develop --local Metalhead
```

This will create a new folder `dev/Metalhead` inside your current project folder. You will need to start Julia with `julia --project=.` where `.` refers to your project folder.

Then you can make changes to your packages and instead of `using` use `include` to load your local dev package:

```
include("dev/Metalhead/src/Metalhead.jl")
```

This will give you a warning like so:

```
WARNING: replacing module Metalhead.
Main.Metalhead
```

But after that you can use all the functions inside Metalhead, including your new ones, e.g.:

```
julia> Metalhead.AlexNet
Main.Metalhead.AlexNet
```

I tested this by adding a dummy function to Metalhead, but there might be more elegant solution out there.

[This video about package development is old](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QVmU29rCjaA&list=PLbN46reHdxCAbszOHo9LywdLv33DBKWpD&index=1&t=1147s), but still you might be able to take some tips from Chris, so I recommend you check it out.